# how to get primaryStage refrence in Javafx2 Controller

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, fxml

now my jdk7 and javafx2 is the newest.
and i would like to code as this way :
UI -> FXML (then define controller in .fxml of the top node ) with scene builder.
Controller -> the class defined in .fxml .

then i write the logic things in Controller class.

there's a trouble or just my question , how to get the Stage refrence in Controller , 
as sometimes i need to controller my stage.

(Sorry that my English is poor , but the meaning is almost looks like above)

pls tell me the way to do that , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you bind the elements with the scene with there root elements
then you are able to get the stage reference which you bind with them

```
Stage stage = (Stage)controlObj.getScene().getWindow();
```